# Command Logs Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-administration

Is there anyway that i can log all the commands that a certain user or user group has run in an ubuntu CLI.
I need to keep a track of all the commands run by a certain group of users say

> **UsrGrp1:usr1,usr2,usr3**

as i'm running a Cluster of machines and all are being controlled by different users. And i need to monitor those through the root user of every machine.

The **history** command gives me all the command logs. But it can be modified by the user itself. So i need to keep the logs under the root user only.

Comment: And what happens if the user types `bash` and then type commands in that shell? You probably want auditing....

Comment: what would a bash command do?? i'm not clear about its functioning..
i'm naive in using linux. please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [logkeys](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/) a keylogger for linux. Another options could be [script](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) but with this you need to write a trigger to start it at each user login.